# Method that takes a lot of parameters

Tags: c#, parameters, coding-style

I have a quite general question about parameters in C#.

I sometimes end up with methods that need a lot of parameters, specifically when making GridViews searchable.

Take this example:

```
searchSQL(
    tbEID.Text, 
    tbSID.Text, 
    tbCID.Text, 
    tbSP.Text, 
    tbSA.Text, 
    tbSMF.Text, 
    tbSS.Text, 
    tbSSC.Text, 
    tbSST.Text, 
    tbSIPA.Text, 
    (string)ViewState["SortExpression"], 
    (string)ViewState["SortDirection"], 
    (tbFromDate.Text == "") ? (DateTime?)null : Convert.ToDateTime(tbFromDate.Text), 
    (tbToDate.Text == "") ? (DateTime?)null : Convert.ToDateTime(tbToDate.Text), 
    (tbSAC.Text == "") ? (int?)null : Convert.ToInt32(tbSAC.Text)
);
```

It works and everything, but it just doesn't look very good IMO.

What would be some possible ways to make this look better? The only way I can think of is to shrink it down by using lists, something like:

```
searchSQL(List<string>, List<DateTime>, int)
```

any other, better alternatives?

Comment: make a class including necessary details and communicate through objects

Comment: In general if method needs more than 3 parameters you need to consider refactoring...

Comment: Wrap your x parameters into a `SearchParameters` class that exists just to transport and contain all those parameters as properties. Then your search method becomes `searchSQL(SearchParameters parameters);` and is very nice and clean. It's also really easy to extend this with additional properties, as needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a class to represent the real world data that is being modelled.

```
class YourNameHere
{
    public string EID { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

That way if you needed to add a value, you can just modify the class - the other code wouldn't have to change, you wouldn't have to be dependent on the index of the properties matching, etc.

You might want to read up on the [concept of encapsulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_(computer_programming)).

Answer (score 2):

You could create a class that would contain only the parameters you want to pass and instead of passing for instance 10 parameters, you could end up passing a reference to this object. This make sense, if the parameters are associated one another. Otherwise, you could make this in two steps.